# Snapshot of Objects in Memory

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am writing a C# WinForms app using VS2008. Is there a way I can view all of the objects that my application has loaded into memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of memory profilers out there.  My personal favorite is Ants profiler from redgate but here are some more:

[Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm)

[MS CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a362781c-3870-43be-8926-862b40aa0cd0&DisplayLang=en)

And also you can follow this SO link for free ones [Free Profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308816/any-good-free-net-profiler)

Answer (score 0):

With a profiler such as the one made by Redgate, this is possible

[ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm?gclid=CMmiovTqy50CFUtp4wodBnx8sQ)